# Error on Git Bash (Windows 7): sh.exe": android: command not found

Tags: android, git, git-bash

I'm having an issue running the **android** key word on Git bash, installed on Windows 7, 64 bit.

The error I get is as below:

```
sh.exe": android: command not found
```

Any one know why this is so?

Comment: May I know why are you using android in git bash ?

Comment: I've got the same issue. I'm running Git Bash because I work mainly with Linux Ubuntu and OSX. Working in this agency where they just work with windows - absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Android SDK path in your system path.I am assuming you have your sdk at this path:**C:\android-sdk-windows**

Can be done in below ways:-

Using command prompt :

```
set path=%path%;C:\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;
```

Another way is to add in your environment variable:-

```
My Computer->Property->Advanced->Environment Variables->Edit Path Variable and add “C:\ android-sdk-windows\tools” & “C:\ android-sdk-windows\platform-tools”into the Path Variables.
```

It is a good practice to do so, because you will be irritated if need to go SDK folder in command prompt always when their is need for it.

Comment: you may need to run as administrator and make sure you close and reopen command prompt/ windows power shell before trying again.